# Google Analytics HTTPS Status -1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics, http-status-codes

I want to implement Google Analytics in my existing native iOS Application which is written in Swift. My Client company hasn't approved Firebase officially, so they're asking me to use Google Analytics only. For this, they provided tracking ID only. When I implement it, using this document https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3 I receive HTTP Status -1 instead of HTTP 200.

My question is, is it possible to implement GA functionality in native iOS without Google-Analytics.plist file ?? If yes, what's the solution ??